# Cannot find module 'internal/util/types' in windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I just tried a lot of solution for this fix. When I do npm install I am getting

```
Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'
```

I tried following solution based on StackOverflow and Git :

1) Removed npm and npm-cache from Appdata/Roaming folder and reinstalled node 8.10.0 and 8.11.3

But still, I am facing  `Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'`

Please help how can I solve this issue?

Advance thanks

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same exact issue on Windows 7 with node 8.11.3. The only thing that worked for me was uninstalling node, deleting the `C:\Program Files\nodejs` folder, and then reinstalling node.

**Note:** it's still a good idea to delete the `npm` and `npm-cache` folders before reinstalling node.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Windows 10

- Remove c:/program files(x86)/nodejs  and or c:/program files/nodejs
  folders manually.
- Remove c:/users/name/appdata/roaming/npm
- Remove c:/users/name/appdata/roaming/npm-cache
- Go to Nodejs.com and download 64 bit stable version and reinstall.