# A module may be missing from 'dependencies' in package.json

Tags: node.js

`Cannot find module 'internal/util/types' is the error I get,
I am trying to build a discord.js bot and push it to heroku

error hint = `A module may be missing from 'dependencies' in package.json`

My require modules codes

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js')
```

my package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.5.1",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0"
  },
```

Comment: Try to remove `node_modules` and lock file. Then install all the packages again.

Comment: just tried that, still getting the same error. @hsz

Comment: can you build it locally? it might be that on heroku is an old node installed and you are using some dependencies that are using a newer version of node

Comment: Have you tried `npm rebuild`? If that does not work, clear your npm cache and reinstall node. 
See: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431593/after-node-reinstalled-cannot-find-module-internal-util-types
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731038/error-cannot-find-module-internal-util-types-while-installing-node-packages
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951689/cannot-find-module-internal-util-types-in-windows-10

Comment: I removed the engine part in package.json and now it works, no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the engines part in package.json and now it works. I am assuming its an issue with node versions.